# Microsoft AutoUpdate on Mac pops up an empty error

Tags: macos, mac, microsoft-office

Lately Microsoft AutoUpdate won't work, just pop up an empty window:

[image]

I tried restarting the computer, reinstalling the autoupdate but still this is what gets popped up. Any idea on how to find out what causes the error and how to fix it?

Comment: You may download and reinstall the latest version of [Microsoft AutoUpdate (MAU)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/officeupdates/release-history-microsoft-autoupdate) to have a check.

Comment: @HerbGu see question: "I tried ... reinstalling the autoupdate". I don't know how I could reinstall without downloading it again, so I did so. Tried multiple versions including the latest one.